# python-opencv, finding centroid of an image

Tags: opencv

I am studying pattern recognition. For study purpose, I extracted faces from bunch of images, and get meaningful features out of them. So I tried to find the centroid of each face image. However, for some of images, I get centroid with coordinate (0,0). The part of code I used to find the centroid is following:

```
################# find the centroid of each faces #################
ret, threshold = cv2.threshold(image, 255/2, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cont, hier = cv2.findContours(threshold, 1, 2)
moment = cv2.moments(cont[0])
if moment['m00'] == 0:
    m00 = 0.01
else:
    m00 = moment['m00']
cx, cy = int(moment['m10']/m00), int(moment['m01']/m00)
###################################################################
```

I am assigning m00 = 0.01 because some of the value moment['m00'] gives zero. 
My question is am I doing correct to find the centroid of an image?? And if it is, why some of the centroid is (0,0)?? I thought since each image is not just blank image, the centroid coordinate should be non-zero coordinate.
Thanks.

Comment: if `m00 == 0` then `m01 == m10 == 0`, therefore `cx == cy == 0`. Have you tried using `drawContours` to see what they look like?

Comment: @beaker Oh, why is that?? Why is if m00== 0 then m01 == 0?? I thought they are different values. I don't really understand how this moment function works. I just read tutorial. And I will try the drawContours function.

Comment: @beaker drawContours not working I think. Do you know any case when the centroid is (0,0)??

Comment: See: [Image moment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moments#Raw_moments)

Comment: I would check to see how many points are in the contours you're trying to draw.